# EVault order on Bare Metal server ends with an error

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am basically following what was posted here to order an EVault on bare metal server:  [Sample code for ordering an EVault backup in SoftLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319257/sample-code-for-ordering-an-evault-backup-in-softlayer)

It works for Virtual Guest, but fails on Bare Metal server on verifyOrder call with an error message like this:

```
There was an error querying the SoftLayer API: EVault orders must be tied to exactly 1 server.
```

This is the kind of input that I have and I only have 1 hardware specified and I do not understand why it thinks I don't have exactly 1 server.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [location] => 168642
    [packageId] => 0
    [prices] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 22747
                )

        )

    [quantity] => 1
    [useHourlyPricing] =>
    [hardware] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 168137
                )

        )
)
```

This is the PHP code that I am using to test. (I've removed some initial require statements). It's referencing an hourly bare metal server and all data shown in sample are real except for $apiUsername and $apiKey:

```
<?php
$apiUsername = 'xxxxx';
$apiKey = 'xxxxx';

$hardware = new stdClass();
$hardware->id = 168137;

$orderHardware = array
(
    $hardware
);

# The location for the Evault
$location = "168642";
$packageId = 0;
$quantity = 1;

$prices = array
(
    22747,
);

// Convert our item list into an array of skeleton
$orderPrices = array();

foreach ($prices as $priceId) {
    $price = new stdClass();
    $price->id = $priceId;
    $orderPrices[] = $price;
}

// Build a SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault object containing
// the order you wish to place.
$orderTemplate = new stdClass();
$orderTemplate->location         = $location;
$orderTemplate->packageId        = $packageId;
$orderTemplate->prices           = $orderPrices;
$orderTemplate->quantity         = $quantity;
$orderTemplate->useHourlyPricing = false;
$orderTemplate->hardware    = $orderHardware;

print_r($orderTemplate);

// Place the order.
try {
    // Re-declare the order template as a SOAP variable, so the SoftLayer
    // ordering system knows what type of order you're placing.
    $orderTemplate = new SoapVar
    (
            $orderTemplate,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault',
            'http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/'
    );

    $softLayer_product_order = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Product_Order', null, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
    $receipt = $softLayer_product_order->verifyOrder($orderTemplate);
    print_r($receipt);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Unable to place server order: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

This is the bare metal server(168137) data that I gather by doing

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/168137/getObject.json?objectMask=activeTransaction.transactionGroup

{
   "accountId" : 79###,
   "bareMetalInstanceFlag" : 0,
   "domain" : "x.net",
   "fullyQualifiedDomainName" : "x.x.net",
   "globalIdentifier" : "2###-##a-4#7-a##6-ed##5",
   "hardwareFunction" : {
      "code" : "WEBSVR",
      "description" : "Web Server",
      "id" : 3
   },
   "hardwareStatus" : {
      "id" : 5,
      "status" : "ACTIVE"
   },
   "hardwareStatusId" : 5,
   "hostname" : "xxxxx",
   "id" : 168137,
   "managedResourceFlag" : false,
   "manufacturerSerialNumber" : "S0#####2009275E",
   "networkManagementIpAddress" : "10.##.###.###",
   "notes" : "",
   "primaryBackendIpAddress" : "10.##.###.###",
   "primaryIpAddress" : "198.##.###.###",
   "privateIpAddress" : "10.##.###.###",
   "provisionDate" : "2016-01-15T09:20:55-06:00",
   "serialNumber" : "ASL####",
   "serviceProviderId" : 1,
   "serviceProviderResourceId" : 168137
}
```

Comment: first your using PHP it would be good idea paste your code to take a look, second did you try the Rest example that mcruz sent you?

Comment: I've updated my question with a test code that I am  using.  Please review and see if you find any issue and please let me know if you do see something.  Thanks.

Comment: The code is running fine for me. If you still having issues with this I recommend you to submit a ticket in Softlayer, something might be wrong with your account.

Answer (score 0):

You’re right, the extra attributes “networkType” and “numOfTabs” are reason of this error.

Errors displayed using these attributes:

```
{
"error": "The property 'networkType' is not valid for 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault'."
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}

{
"error": "The property 'numOfTabs' is not valid for 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault'."
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

If you remove them, the order will work successfully.

Below is a REST example removing these attributes:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json

Method: POST

{
  "parameters": [
    {
   "complexType" : "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault",
   "hardware" : [
      {
         "id" : "149654",
         "notes" : "Bare Metal"
      }
   ],
   "location" : "449500",
   "packageId" : 0,
   "prices" : [
      {
         "id" : "83867"
      }
   ],
   "quantity" : 1,
   "useHourlyPricing" : 0
}
  ]
}
```

References:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault

**EDIT**

But if the order still has errors, we need to review other kind of possible issues. For example, one of them could be a problem with the bar metal that we are using. We can review if it may have an active transaction running that stop our order. To get if this server has active transactions, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/149654/getObject?objectMask=activeTransaction.transactionGroup

Method: GET 
where: “149654” is the Hardware_id.
```

If the Bar metal has active transaction, the result will display something like this:

```
"serviceProviderResourceId": 149654
"globalIdentifier": "aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-8851-c3c68f764a4e"
"hardwareFunction": {
"code": "WEBSVR"
"description": "Web Server"
"id": 3
}-
"hardwareStatus": {
"id": 8
"status": "RECLAIM"
}-
"managedResourceFlag": false
"networkManagementIpAddress": "11.11.11.11"
"primaryBackendIpAddress": "10.44.44.44"
"primaryIpAddress": "50.50.50.50"
"activeTransaction": {
"createDate": "2016-01-15T08:54:04-06:00"
"elapsedSeconds": 10328
"guestId": null
"hardwareId": 149654
"id": 1234567
"modifyDate": "2016-01-15T12:45:31-06:00"
"statusChangeDate": "2016-01-15T10:07:22-06:00"
"transactionGroup": {
"averageTimeToComplete": "641.64"
"name": "Reclaim Server"
}-
"transactionStatus": {
"averageDuration": "162.31"
"name": "XX_ERASEDRIVES"
}-
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the new input which I've removed the extra attributes.  Yet I still run into same problem..

Comment: @KHP, currently the barmetal with id = 149654 has an active transaction, for that reason the order cannot be executed successfully. Please see EDIT in the answer to get the active transaction using a request. I hope it help you. Regards

Comment: Oh?  When does it become to some other state? or what state does it need to be and how can I set it to that state?

Comment: I’m able to get these errors when executing the order using REST requests with “Advanced Rest Client App” for Chrome. In my experience I saw more error details using REST :)

Comment: Also, the active transaction has to be completed itself, the customer is not able to manipulate this execution (In this case it seems that your server is being reclaimed and it will not be used anymore). But when a server is active, its status is "ACTIVE" and the "active transaction" is "NULL" (if we execute the last request that I posted, the active transaction won't be displayed in the result).

Comment: I've added the latest status of my device in my question at the bottom.  Based on your last comment, my device is ACTIVE, and I don't have any active transaction.  So it should be in valid state to place an EVault order on it.  I've created a PHP code that I am running locally now to reproduce this issue and in that, it doesn't show error about other extra attributes.  But did remove them anyway.

Comment: How did you determine that my bare metal is not available to add EVault?  Where in the customer portal and what data does it tell that?  I just went to the SoftLayer customer portal and clicked on my bare metal device, then went to the storage section and clicked on "add" on EVault and I can select location, size, and looks like verifying the order part works though I didn't complete the order.

Comment: I've updated my question with the sample PHP code that I am using. Please check and see if you see something that I am doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to execute successfully the php script.

Comment: Is your bare metal server an hourly or monthly? I wonder if it makes any difference. Would you be able to post the detail on  your bare metal server that you used here?